# Report generator windows service polling database for work

Tags: architecture, services, parallel-programming

I'm building a new report generator for our in-house survey system. (No I can not use any off-the-shelf software. These are highly customized reports.)

I want to use [Topshelf](http://www.topshelf-project.com) to host the generator as a service. Our current generator is a desktop-app and requires a user to be logged in on the server. I want to try to avoid this.

The report-generation itself is very straight forward and procedural in nature. But the server is more than capable of generating several reports at one time. I want the service to spin up a few instances of the generator at the same time, is this something I would use the Task Parallel Library for? A bit of pseudo would look a bit like this:

```
poller.Poll(order => { // blocking(?) call to listen for new report-orders
  var gen = new Generator(order);
  gen.process(); // generates report
  set gen = null; // or something else to destroy the generator for that report
});
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: how do the report-job-entries come into the database? Are they triggerd by date/time rules (a la ever tuesday at 6pm)?. The soloutions i am aware of either implement [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) that react when sombody wants a report or the timer engine calculates when the next event should occur and set a timer to this.

Comment: The report orders come into the database on demand. Our web-interface exposes a report builder. Our customers use this to create their specific reports. I have been thinking about going the queue-route (RabbitMQ or such) but I am not able to do any major rewrites on the web application at this time. (I am doing a complete rewrite in the future though)